# C# - Use multiple types as parameters without writing multiple definitions?

Tags: c#, parameters

I have a constructor of a class and need to feed it parameters of different types. I know I can write the constructors with different signatures but that is a bit painful.

Is there a way to allow a parameter to be one of two different types:

What I need to do:

```
public Line(Coordinate p1, Coordinate p2)
    {}

public Line(Point3d p1, Point3d p2)
    {}

public Line(Point3d p1, Coordinate p2)
    {}

public Line(Coordinate p1, Point3d p2)
    {}
```

Is there a way to write one constructor that takes the two parameters as either only a Coordinate or a Point3d without writing four different constructors?

Comment: You could take Line(Object[] args) and check the options match your criteria

Comment: What's the difference between `Coordinate` and `Point3d`? Does it perhaps make sense for either to be convertible to the other, using an implicit conversion operator? That way, you'd only have to support one of them explicitly in the constructor.

Comment: The only real way to do this is where inheritance/interface implementations are available and/or you can use generics - which you can't really do for a constructor without making the whole class generic.

Comment: Having to write several constructor (or method) overloads is the smallest price for having strong types inside them. Don't need strong type? Just use `object`. Btw, all those strong typed constructors can call the same generic method if work is the same and can be extracted into a method.

Answer (score 1):

You have several options when doing this. My suggestions would be either to create an interface containing shared methods and attributes or use boxing/unboxing to pass the parameters as objects and cast them to whichever type you need.

For the interface method you will need to define a common interface:

```
public interface ICoordinatePoint
{
    void SomeMethod();
    int someAttribute;
}
```

Then when defining your classes, implement this interface

```
public class Coordinate : ICoordinatePoint
public class Point3d : ICoordinatePoint
```

In your function, just pass the variables as `ICoordinatePoint`s

```
public Line(ICoordinatePoint p1, ICoordinatePoint p2)
{
    // Some stuff
}
```

If you want to use boxing/unboxing, you can just defins `p1` and `p2` as objects:

```
public Line(object _p1, object _p2)
{
    Coordinate p1 = (Coordinate)_p1;
    Point3d p2 = (Point3d)_p2;
    // Some stuff
}
```

Edit: If you want to insure that your objects are not of any other types, you can check the types before casting:

```
if (p1.GetType() != typeof(Coordinate) && p1.GetType() != typeof(Point3d)
    // Raise error or return
if (p2.GetType() != typeof(Coordinate) && p1.GetType() != typeof(Point3d)
    // Raise error or return
```

Comment: Interface method is the only one viable, because OP need the constructor to accept only specified classes. Object constructor will accept any object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use interface as parameter for constructor. Then you will need to provide a class that implement that interface as a parameter.

```
public interface IClassInterface
{}
```

Then you need to implement that interface into you classes.

```
public Class : IClassInterface
{}
```

And last you need to use that interface as a parameter for constructor.

```
public Line(IClassInterface p1, IClassInterface p2)
{}
```

This way, your constructor will accept only classes with specified interface as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You could try optional parameters. The following will allow any combination of the variables, including all nulls. You would need to check for all these combinations within the constructor though.

```
public Line(Coordinate c1 = null, Coordinate c2 = null, Point3d p1 = null, Point3d p2 = null)
{}
```

If you go this route you may want to only create a line if certain conditions are right. For this consider the following design pattern. Make the constructor private and create a static method to return a new Line only if conditions are met.

```
public class Line{
    private Line(Coordinate c1 = null, Coordinate c2 = null, Point3d p1 = null, Point3d p2 = null)
    {}

    public static Line CreateLine(Coordinate c1 = null, Coordinate c2 = null, Point3d p1 = null, Point3d p2 = null)
    {
        if (/* favorable condition*/)
            return new Line(c1, c2, p1, p2);
        return null;
    }
}
```

If Coordinate and Point3d did implement a common interface, I would also suggest using generics

```
public class Line<T1, T2>
    where T1: ICommonInterface
    where T2: ICommonInterface
{
    public Line(T1 p1, T2 p2)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Constructor with optional parameters is pretty crazy idea: `var line = new Line(c1: someCoordinate, p2: somePoint)`.. but as you can see there is no way to force to pass 2 parameters.. what should be constructed if someone pass 4? or none?

Comment: I've updated my post to include a different pattern for the optional parameters route.

Answer (score 0):

We would want to have an interface that can back both Coordinate and Point3d. If there is functionality that both share then you can create a base class (which could be abstract as well if we don't want it instantiated)

```
public class Coordinate :IBasePoint
{
}

public class Point3d:IBasePoint
{
}
```

and then use it as follows

```
public class Line
{
  public Line(IBasePoint p1, IBasePoint p2){}
}
```

If you can share common functionality, you might want to implement a Base class

```
public abstract class BasePoint
{
  //shared logic
}

public class Coordinate:BasePoint
{
}

public class Point3d:BasePoint
{
}
```

and then use it as follows

```
public class Line
{
  public Line(BasePoint p1, BasePoint p2)
  {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One assumption most of the answers here are making is that you have the ability to update the Coordinate or the Point3d classes, so that you can implement an interface or add a base class.  Assuming this is not the case, your best solution may be to implement the facade pattern so you can extract out the parts of the Coordinate or Point3d classes (or any other acceptable type) that you need into a single simplified class or interface.

This allows you to have a single constructor with strongly typed parameters that contain exactly what you need to use in your class and none of the additional baggage that would come with the Coordinate or Point3d class.